# R raster extract polygon ID from xy coordinates of a point

Tags: r, r-raster

I would like to extract the polygon ID in which a point is located. I have tried multiple solutions but I could not figure out how to do it. Currently my code is the following:

```
r1<-raster(xmn=-111.4567,
       xmx=136.841,
       ymn=-94.39192,
       ymx=123.5581,
       res=50) 
r1 = rasterToPolygons(r1)
d = cbind("x" = 7.36459732, "y"=  30.4465762)
extract(r1,d)
```

EDIT1:
If I get the grid coordinates from the raster, polygon ID of d should be 13 (as d is between -36.45 & 13.54 in x axis and between -1.44 and 48.55)

```
r1<-raster(xmn=-111.4567,
       xmx=136.841,
       ymn=-94.39192,
       ymx=123.5581,
       resolution=50) 

cells<-cellFromRowColCombine(r1, 1:dim(r1)[1],1:dim(r1)[2])
coord_grid<-data.frame(xyFromCell(r1,cells),id=cells)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? The above code produces the output I would expect from the given input. Are you getting an error message, or do you think the output should be different somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution I found: cellFromXY(r1, d)